# What are the steps involved to share the credentials with multiple applications?

Tags: authentication, data-transfer, database-administration, two-factor-authentication

I have 2 scenarios here.

1. app1 and app2 both belong to the same domain
2. app1 and app2 both do not belong to the same domain.

For both scenarios, I require the responsibilities of frontend and backend of:

1. A person logging to app1 and he selects some device, after he wants to take device information to app2, (app2 may or may not be in the same domain)
2. After landing on app2 - all his editing or deleting should impact on his account.
3. When he logs out on app2 - that should not impact app1 (both vice-versa)

Both applications are using `jwt` based authentication. (using oAuth)

I don't know how to handle this scenario, and I am not able to understand what the frontend needs to do for this, or what the backend needs to take care.

How can this be handled? (guess both apps using angularjs with token based authentication)

Comment: "I don't know how to handle this scenario" - Which one you describe two fundamentally different setups.  Although it isn't clear how oAuth would be impacted by either scenario.  Just use the same oAuth.

Comment: how can i use the same credientails in other application? how to communicate both?

Comment: Use a common source for the credentials, or authenticate against either one of the domains, if they are separate.

Comment: but i require to transfer data from one app to another - ? do you have any article or tutorials?

Comment: "do you have any article or tutorials?" - Hundreds.  Questions seeking learning materials are not on topic though so I cannot answer that question.